# direct sum of vector finite subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to prove that this is true:

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W_{1},W_{2},...,W_{n}$ vector subspaces of $V$ then.

$W_{1}+W_{2}+...+W_{n}$ is a direct sum $\Leftrightarrow$ the only way to write  $\vec{0}_{v}=\vec{x}_{1}+\vec{x}_{2}+...+\vec{x}_{n}$  where $\vec{x}_{i}\in W_{i}$ and $\vec{x}_{i}=\vec{0}_{v}$

I've tried this for the first part:

$\vec{0}_{v}\in V \hspace{1cm}$ and $\hspace{1cm} V=W_{1}\oplus W_{2}\oplus ... \oplus W_{n} \implies \exists!x_{i}\in W_{i}\hspace{0.2cm}$ such that $\vec{0}_{v}=\vec{x}_{1}+\vec{x}_{2}+...+\vec{x}_{n}$

also:

$\vec{0}_{v}=\vec{0}_{v}+\vec{0}_{v}+...+\vec{0}_{v}\hspace{0.2cm}\land\hspace{0.2cm}\vec{0}_{v}\in W_{i} \hspace{1cm}$

then:

$\vec{0}_{v}=\vec{0}_{v}+\vec{0}_{v}+...+\vec{0}_{v}\hspace{0.2cm}\land\hspace{0.2cm}\exists!x_{i}\in W_{i}\hspace{0.2cm}$such that $\hspace{0.2cm}\vec{0}_{v}=\vec{x}_{1}+\vec{x}_{2}+...+\vec{x}_{n} \implies \vec{0}_{v}=\vec{x}_{i}\hspace{0.2cm}\forall\vec{x}_{i}\in W_{i}$

$\therefore V=W_{1}\oplus W_{2}\oplus ... \oplus W_{n} \implies \vec{0}_{v}=\vec{x}_{i}\hspace{0.2cm}\forall\vec{x}_{i}\in W_{i}$

(I think that this may be wrong)

I got stuck in the second part, i don't know even how to start it

Comment: Do you define direct sum as this: Any vector $v\in W_1\oplus W_2\oplus\cdots\oplus W_n$ can be expressed uniquely as $v=w_1+w_2+\cdots+w_n$, where $w_i\in W_i$?

Comment: no, the definition of my professor is that $V=W_{1}+W_{2} \land W_{1}\cap W_{2}=\{\vec{0}_{v}\}$ but I can use that theorem

Comment: @EdsonFlorianoFigueroa Your professor's condition works for the sum of *two* subspaces.

Comment: In the proof that you gave looks like you know that $W_1 + \cdots + W_n$ is direct if and only if the every vector $v \in W_1 + \cdots + W_n$ can be written in a unique way as $v = w_1 + \cdots + w_n$ for $w_i \in W_i$. Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$\Leftarrow$ part:**

Suppose there is a vector $v\in W_1+W_2+\cdots+W_n$ which can be written as $$v=w_1+w_2+\cdots+w_n=w_1'+w_2'+\cdots+w_n',\ \text{with}\ w_i,w_i'\in W_i$$ Then $$\vec{0}=(w_1-w_1')+(w_2-w_2')+\cdots+(w_n-w_n')$$ Now $w_i,w_i'\in W_i$ implies that $w_i-w_i'\in W_i$ as $W_i$ is a vector space. Now by our assumption $w_i-w_i'=\vec{0}$, or $w_i=w_i'$.

Thus every vector $v\in W_1+ W_2+\cdots+W_n$ can be uniquely expressed as $v=w_1+w_2+\cdots+w_n$ with $w_i\in W_i$. But this implies that the sum $W_1+W_2+\cdots+W_n$ is indeed direct.

Comment: thanks, you helped me a lot :)